# What PSU to use with antminer s7

Tags: mining-setup, antminer

I'm planning to buy myself a Bitmain Antminer S7 Batch 9.

Unfortunately, the Bitmain PSU (APW3-12-1600-B2) is not available to me, and I need to replace it with a regular PSU from another shop.

I think S7 needs a 9 6pin PCI-E connector. I haven't seen a 9 6pin PSU ever.

Which PSU could power my S7?

Comment: The product description mentions that the S7 uses [3 PCI-e connectors for +12V DC input](https://www.bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=00020151212042549033J27u55CO0610). Does that resolve your question?

Comment: No actually I asked for your recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 9X of the 6-pin PCI-e connections to make this work with your miner.  You need about 1350 watts for this to account for the ±10% requirements for nominal running, perhaps more if you plan to overclock it.  They also say not to run it with more than one PSU per board, that may be tricky, because I would have normally said to perhaps get a three CX750s to run or perhaps my juggernaut Evo 1500ewt. If you’re interested I’ve got a couple laying around.  Despite that… you would still need another one as my own PSU only has six available 20A connections.

[image: See the three little rows of white pins that's where you connect the 12V psu connections! Don’t combine connections from psus on the same board or it could break your miner]

As @murch points out, if you have 1300 watts per device that means you have at least 450 with zero headroom. So if you split it, you need at least 500 watts with the proper headroom without considering overclocking all the way.

Comment: You seem to know a bit about setting up miners, the asker had a [follow-up question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/42708/5406), could you please have a look?