# What power cord to use with BITMAIN PSU?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-setup, antminer, psu

As I introduced in my previous question which no one answered I'm having some problems with bitmain's power cord

So the simple main question is what power  cord to use ??

I used a 250v 10-16A 3*0.75mm^2
And had problems

[My previous post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42708/antminer-s7-turned-off-automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least 3*1.5 (14awg) wire

Comment: Perhaps you could add some information as to how you know that or why this is the correct answer.